# Import deployed .js into Angular Universal server app

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I am using the nice solution of using an `env.js` file, adding the environment variables to the `window`-object in Angular. This way I can change environement-vars without rebuilding the code.

```js
const env = {
  apiUrl: 'http://api.url'
};

(function (window) {
  window['env'] = window['env'] || env;
})(this);
```

Then in my `environment.ts`-file I can use it like this:

```
export const environment = {
  apiUrl: window['env']?.apiUrl || 'default.url'
};
```

I am now adding Universal support to this application and obviously run into the issue, that `window is not defined` in the Universal code.

I now wrapped the environments into a service to abstract away the dependency and to allow for checking if I am in a browser or on the server. Now it should be possible to read the `env.js` from the server code, right? I would like to read the `const env` in order to have the environment vars also in the server side code.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EnvironmentService {
  private env;

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId) {
    if (this.isBrowser())
      this.env = {
        production: environment.production,
        apiUrl: `${window['env']?.apiUrl}`
      };
    else {
      // something like this?!
      const envFromJs = require('env.js');
      this.env = envFromJs;
    }
  }

  private isBrowser(): boolean {
    return isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
  }

  public getEnvironment(): IEnvironment {
    return this.env;
  }
}
```

No matter what path I put into the require, I cannot get this to work.